# How can I remove any UTF-8 BOM that exists -within- some text, not at the start of some text

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8, byte-order-mark

We receive some files, which have been concatenated by another party. In the middle of these files are some `BOM` characters.

Is there a way we can detect these 3 chars and remove them? I've seen plenty of examples about how to remove the `BOM` from the -start- of a file ... but not the middle.

Comment: You should load the file in binary mode (Stream), have three bytes in some buffer and skip the 'copy' (writing to output string) once you see `EFBBBF`.

Comment: String.Replace("\ufffe", "") would be an obvious workaround.  As long as these BOMs are the same of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your file is small enough to hold in memory, and that you have an `Enumerable.Replace` extension method for replacing subsequences, then you could use:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var bom = new byte[] { 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF };
var empty = Enumerable.Empty<byte>();
bytes = bytes.Replace(bom, empty).ToArray();
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
```

Here is a simple (inefficient) implementation of the `Replace` extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Replace<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    IEnumerable<TSource> match,
    IEnumerable<TSource> replacement)
{
    return Replace(source, match, replacement, EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default);
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> Replace<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    IEnumerable<TSource> match,
    IEnumerable<TSource> replacement,
    IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    int sLength = source.Count();
    int mLength = match.Count();

    if (sLength < mLength || mLength == 0)
        return source;

    int[] matchIndexes = (
        from sIndex in Enumerable.Range(0, sLength - mLength + 1)
        where source.Skip(sIndex).Take(mLength).SequenceEqual(match, comparer)
        select sIndex
    ).ToArray();

    var result = new List<TSource>();
    int sPosition = 0;
    foreach (int mPosition in matchIndexes)
    {
        var sPart = source.Skip(sPosition).Take(mPosition - sPosition);
        result.AddRange(sPart);
        result.AddRange(replacement);
        sPosition = mPosition + mLength;
    }

    var sLastPart = source.Skip(sPosition).Take(sLength - sPosition);
    result.AddRange(sLastPart);
    return result;
}
```